# How to use $ http.get () of angularjs 1.6 with url with parameters

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I'm using nodejs and angularjs but I do not understand how to get the data from nodejs to angular, I'll leave my code here

App.js angular

```
Var myApp = angular.module ('angularTodo', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);


MyApp.controller ('mainController', ['$ scope', '$ http', function ($ scope, $ http) {

   $ Http.get ('/ api / all'). Then (function (res) {
       $ Scope.pacientes = res.data;

       $ Scope.sort = function (keyname) {
               $ Scope.sortKey = keyname; // set the sortKey to the param passed
               $ Scope.reverse =! $ Scope.reverse; // if true make it false and vice versa
           }
   }). Finally (function () {
       $ Scope.example7 + = "(Finally called)";
   });


}]);

MyApp.controller ('patient', ['$ scope', '$ http', function ($ scope, $ http)

   $ Http.get ('/ patient /: id') .then (function (res) {
       $ Scope.new = res.data.pk;
       $ Scope.test = "test11";
   }). Finally (function () {
       $ Scope.example7 + = "(Finally called)";
   });


}]);
```

Routes.js

```
App.get ('/ patient /: id', function (req, res) {

Var id = req.params.id;

Connection.query ('SELECT * FROM patient WHERE pat_id =?', [Id], function (err, data)
        {

            If (err)
                Console.log ("Error Selecting:% s", err);

            Res.json (data [0]);
            Console.log (id);
            Console.log (data);

         });



});

App.get ('/ newinf /: id', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {

     Res.render ('informe.ejs', {user: req.user});

});
```

The problem is that $ http.get ('/ patient /: id') is not receiving the id? How do I get the id of the url in angularjs?

Comment: Please fix your code, there are a lot of unwanted spaces in variable names, functions...

Answer (score 0):

In a factory you can define a function that makes an http request .

```
MyApp.factory('test_factory',function($http,{
    factory = {};
    factory.get_request = function(params){
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'some_url',
            params: params
        })
    };
    return factory
});
```

In your controller you can make the http request defined in your factory (make sure to DI your factory).  Notice how I'm passing an object to the get_request function within the factory.

```
MyApp.controller('some_ctrl',function($scope,test_factory){
    test_factory.get_request({id:12345}).then(function(data){
        console.log(data)
    })
});
```

Of course you can make a http request directly from your controller using basically the same syntax.  But it is usually much better practice to separate the request logic into a factory.

Also, since you are making a GET request, the query params will be added to the url string when the request is made.  You can confirm this by checking the network tab in most browsers developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the id yourself as part of the url in your request. In angular, you are currently sending a request to `/patient/:id`. Try replacing the `:id` in your angular code with a valid id of a patient in your database. For example:

```
$http.get('/patient/12')
    .then(function (res) {...})
```

12 should then show up as your `req.param.id` in your server side code.

I'd also recommend that you follow user2263572's advice and encapsulate this logic into a factory as well.